# Get a list of venues from a JSON response

Tags: android, json, foursquare

I am getting a list of venues near of a location (latitude/longitude) from the Foursquare API, I obtain a JSONObject, but I'm a noob, and I don't know how can I get a list of the response only with name, location, and less more.

It seems that the JSON from the Foursquare has changes from the last version, this is why I'm asking it.

For example
[Foursquare API Explorer](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/explore#req=venues/search?ll=40.7,-74)

I'm trying to do with this.

```
public void showVenues() {
    // Objeto Conexion HTTP - Libreria AsyncHttpClient
    AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
    // Genero la conexion, mediante URL, Parameters, Listener(Json)
    Log.i("FOURSQUAREQUERY", getFOURSQUAREQUERY());
    client.get(getFOURSQUAREQUERY(), null, new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {
        // Evento onSuccess disparado cuando se descarga
        // correctamente la informacion
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(JSONObject data) {
            try {
                // js = new JSONObject(s);
                Log.i("JSON", data.toString());
                JSONArray venues = data.getJSONObject("response")
                        .getJSONArray("venues");
                List<JSONObject> venue_names = new ArrayList<JSONObject>();
                for (int i = 0; i < venues.length(); i++) {
                    JSONArray items = venues.optJSONObject(i).getJSONArray(
                            "name");
                    for (int j = 0; j < items.length(); j++) {
                        JSONObject tempObj = new JSONObject();
                        tempObj.put("name", items.optJSONObject(j)
                                .getJSONObject("venue").optString("name"));
                        tempObj.put(
                                "address",
                                items.optJSONObject(j)
                                        .getJSONObject("venue")
                                        .getJSONObject("location")
                                        .optString("address"));
                        tempObj.put(
                                "distance",
                                items.optJSONObject(j)
                                        .getJSONObject("venue")
                                        .getJSONObject("location")
                                        .optInt("distance"));
                        venue_names.add(tempObj);
                        Log.i("TEMPOBJECT", tempObj.toString());
                    }
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable arg0) {

        }
    });

};
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're doing

```
JSONArray items = venues.optJSONObject(i).getJSONArray("name");
```

If you change this to a String, this may solve some of your problems (since "name" is not an array but a String)